# Is it possible to get the pointer the continous memory fragment in a std::vector<char> in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, vector, malloc

I moved my code to use `std::vector<char>` instead of `char *mem = malloc(...)` but now I am facing a problem that I can only access the vector data through `operator []` but not via a pointer.

I can't write stuff like:

```
std::vector<char> data;
fill_data(data);
char *ptr = data;
```

Before I could do this:

```
char *data = malloc(100);
fill_data2(data);
char *ptr = data;
```

Any ideas if it's still possible to access data in a `vector` via pointer?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard way to access the vector data is to use

```
&data[0]
```

Comment: In the future, C++0x will add a `data()` member to do this slightly more explicitly.

Comment: But beware reallocation of vector.

Comment: Does the C++ standard guarantee that the memory is stored in a contiguous block? **EDIT**: Yes, see the Herb Sutter article.

Comment: @Philipp: yes indeed, simply because `vector` was created with C-compatibility in mind. When C-compatibility isn't mandated, it's best to use `deque` because of its more stringent iterator validity requirement and its better performance (in general).

Answer (score 2):

Of course. The vector was designed for this purpose:

```
char * p = &(myVector[0]) ;
```

And now, p points to the first item in the vector, and you can access each item by playing with the pointer, as you would in C.

Comment: @bodacydo And something to give you more insights: http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/

Answer (score 0):

You can write that code perfectly legally. All you need to do is alter fill_data to take a `std::vector<T>&`. Of course, if this is an external C API, then you don't have much choice in the matter.