# Char * of std::vector<char>

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to get the pointer the continous memory fragment in a std::vector<char> in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521054/is-it-possible-to-get-the-pointer-the-continous-memory-fragment-in-a-stdvector)

How do I get `char*` from `std::vector<char>`, just like the function `std::string.c_str()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the adress of the first element:

```
char * foo = &my_vec[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand slightly on space_cowboy's answer...

You can do:

```
std::vector<char> vec;
vec.push_back('a');
vec.push_back('b');
vec.push_back('c');

char *arr = &vec[0];
```

However, if you were to now do a `push_back`...

```
vec.push_back('d');
arr; // This pointer has been possibly invalidated!
     // realloc could have been called on vec's memory.
```